# PHP CSV, how to get previous and next 3 rows from current row

Tags: php, csv

I am currently using fgetcsv in php to get rows in CSV file. For each row, I need it's 3 previous rows and 3 next rows for some requirement.

```
while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    //$data is current row data
    //I need previous rows and next rows data
}
```

I don't know how to try this, as each while iterate will be having the current row's information.

Is there anything we can achieve this within the fgetcsv loop? I am also open for other alternatives for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store these rows yourself.

I would do something like this:

```
$rows = array();

$index = 0;

while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $rows[] = $data;

    if($index >= 6) {
        $currentIndex = $index - 4;
        $currentRow = $rows[$currentIndex];
        //Do something with $rows[$currentRowIndex +- 3];    
    }
    $index++;
}
```

If the data is too big to keep it all stored in an array, you could also opt to only store at most 7 rows, and operate on row 4:

```
$rows = array();

while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $rows[] = $data;
    if(count($rows) == 7) {
        $currentRow = $rows[4];
        //Do something with $rows[0-6];
        array_shift($rows);    
    }
}
```

Comment: nice, i will try. btw, you forgot to increment `$index`

Answer (score 2):

Add the data to an array, then use a `for` loop:

```
$myData = array();

while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $myData[] = $data;
}

for($i=0; $i<count($myData); $i++)
{
    // $myData[$i] is the current row
}
```

In the `for` loop, you can add or subtract from `$i` to get any row. So for the next row, `$myData[$i+1]`, or next after that `$myData[$i+2]`.

The same goes for previous rows: `$myData[$i-1]`. Be sure to check the row exists before trying to access it. For example, the first row will not have any previous rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = array();
$index = 0;

while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 5000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $rows[] = $data;
    if($index >= 5) {
        $currIndex = $index - 4;
        $previousIndex = $currIndex - 1;
        $nextIndex = $currIndex + 3;

        if(isset($rows[$nextIndex]) && isset($rows[$previousIndex]))
        {
            $nextRow = $rows[$nextIndex];
            $prevRow = $rows[$previousIndex];
        }
    }
    $index++;
}
```